# svyttest to compare a mean to a population mean mu

Tags: r, survey

I am seeking to test for statistically significant difference between two proportions (%) from two different sampling distributions (i.e., % in poor health for male and % in poor health for females) for a binary indicator (% in poor health, % in good health).

Is there a test for a difference in proportion reporting % in poor health, by sex, using a test similar to a t.test with complex survey data, if these data are from different strata?

Answer (score 1):

You could still use `svyttest`, since proportions are perfectly good means.

Or you could fit a regression model with `svyglm`